# Edit row from database using thymeleaf + jpa

Tags: html, spring, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, crud

I am trying to make the data shown in the table be inputs, so i can edit whatever i want. This is why i have used the if-s in thymeleaf. So that when i press the edit button, the id_modific becomes the id of the row i want to change(which i have taken previous from html->this works).
So now, nothing happens, when i press the edit image, nothing happens. :(
What can i do to make it work? Or how can i manage to do what i want using thymeleaf + jpa?

Thank you in advance. You are the best.

Part of the controller:

```
@GetMapping("c/edit/{id}")
public ModelAndView editClientData(@PathVariable(value="id") int id, Model model) {
        Client client = clientDao.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("id_modific", id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/adminhomepage");
    }

@GetMapping("/finish-edit-client")
public String FinishEditClient(@RequestParam("id_client") int id_client,
                                         @RequestParam("nume") String nume,
                                         @RequestParam("prenume") String prenume,
                                         @RequestParam("cnp") String cnp,
                                         @RequestParam("telefon") String telefon,
                                         @RequestParam("email") String email) {
        clientService.modifyClientById(id_client, nume, prenume, cnp, telefon, email);
```

Part of the html code:

```
<tr th:each="c,iStat:${client}"
   th:style="${iStat.odd}? 'font-weight: bold;'"
   th:alt-title="${iStat.even}? 'even' : 'odd'"
   th:with="one=1">
<span th:if="${c.id_client} != ${id_modific}">
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.id_client}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.nume}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.prenume}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.cnp}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.telefon}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.cont_online}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.email}"></td>
   <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.parola}"></td>
   <td><a th:href="@{/c/delete/{id}(id=${c.id_client})}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
     <a th:href="@{/c/edit/{id}(id=${c.id_client})}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> </td>
</span>
<span th:if="${c.id_client} == ${id_modific}">
    <form action="finish-edit-client" method="get">
        <td name = "id_client" style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.id_client}"></td>
        <td><input name="nume" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="prenume" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="cnp" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="telefon" class="form-control"></td>
        <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.cont_online}"></td>
        <td><input name="email" class="form-control"></td>
        <td style = "word-wrap: break-word;" th:text="${c.parola}"></td>
         <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button></td>
</form>
</span>
```

[How a row of the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoFQD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place a `<span>` inside a `<tr>` in this way - that is not valid HTML.

If you are using Thymeleaf `th:if="${...}"` operators to choose between sets of cells, then try using the `<th:block>` tag instead of `<span>`. This is a so-called [synthetic tag](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag), which will be removed by Thymeleaf. But Thymeleaf will keep the contents inside the block - namely, your selected `<td>` tags and their data.